# run command [$ ./vendor/bin/phpunit --coverage-html coverage] is failed

Tags: laravel, phpunit, code-coverage

when I run command

```sh
$ ./vendor/bin/phpunit --coverage-html coverage
```

I got the following message:

> Warning: No code coverage driver available
> 38 / 38 (100%)
> Time: 00:01.128, Memory: 38.00 MB
> OK (38 tests, 140 assertions)
> No coverage report file is generated.

How do I get the file coverage .html?

Comment: you need to install and enable a coverage driver like e.g. [xdebug](https://xdebug.org/)

Comment: Can you guide me specifically on how to install xdebug on windows?

Comment: https://xdebug.org/docs/install#windows can guide you better than I ever could